# How can i handle this termination of app which is running background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, background-process, terminate

On debugging, i send application to background but still running when terminate the app get error with no message.
I can handle directly terminated app with `applicationWillTerminate:`
How can i handle this termination?

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because you lose connection to app and xcode find it as an error.

In [UIApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) you have the method: `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` wich gives you information that the app is about to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle terminate only when app is not in background.